# Div disappears after applying SVG Gaussian blur

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg, svg-filters

I'm trying to apply a Gaussian blur to an element which has some child nodes containing some content.

For Chrome I did in the applied style:

```
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
```

Firefox doesn't support this. What firefox does support is [applying SVG to elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content). Knowing this I searched google for an example where they would explain how to use SVG to apply a gaussian blur to an element. I found [this example](http://css-plus.com/2010/05/how-to-add-a-gaussian-blur-effect-to-elements-within-firefox/) with [this demo](http://css-plus.com/examples/2010/05/how-to-add-a-gaussian-blur-effect-to-elements-within-firefox/).

I brewed up the following CSS:

```
    #div-with-content{
        -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
        filter: url('#blur');
    }
```

And put this into the corresponding `HTML` file:

```
    <svg:svg>
        <svg:filter id="blur">
            <svg:feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
        </svg:filter>
    </svg:svg>
```

But when I went to test the page I saw that `div-with-content` wasn't there anymore. It had disappeared. Everytime I remove the blur style from `div-with-content` it appears again.

Could anyone please help me out on this one, I've really tried everything within my knowledge.

Comment: I think another way to accomplish that is that you add a png with a blur on top of your ellement

Comment: Can you link to your page that shows the problem?  Typically things will "disappear" with SVG if you try to apply a paint server that's not actually valid....

Comment: @dinodsaurus So, your solution would be to let's say create a 100px png  with a gaussian blur. Fill a layer's background with that same png and then place the layer over the element?

Comment: @BorisZbarsky What do you mean by: 'a paint server that's not actually valid'? Do you mean the `<svg>...</svg>` part is not made up in a valid way?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  But it's hard to tell whether that's what's going on or not without seeing the entire page.  One thing worth trying, offhand, is dropping all the "svg:" bits, since I don't think those are allowed in the HTML serialization of SVG.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky [This](http://etine-203.azurewebsites.net) is a link to the site. It's a prototype and a little GUI tryout. You need to login before you'll encounter what I meant, the account details can be anything you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's your apostrophes or your svg: but this version works perfectly in Firefox:

```
CSS:
#div-with-content{
        filter: url("#blur");
    }


HTML:
<svg>
   <filter id="blur">
       <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
   </filter>
</svg>

<div id="div-with-content"> WOohooo</div>
```

Comment: I tried it in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/skcU9/8/) JFiddle and it seems to be working perfectly. I took the piece I would like to blur on the website to have a waterproof comparison.

Comment: It works in the fiddle because js fiddle uses `<style>`.  Your page is probably putting the css in an external css file referenced via `<link>`.  Try putting the blur class in your html document directly, via `<style>`.

Comment: If you want it to be external that's perfectly possible but you must change it from #blur to whateveryourfilenameis.html#blur

Answer (score 1):

If there is only text you would like to blur there is this little trick

```
p{
   color: transparent;
   text-shadow: 0 0 4px #222;
}
```

You can see it here how it works [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4FU2/)

Comment: I came across this trick myself too, unfortunately there is more then text alone upon `div-with-content`

Answer (score 0):

## edit

*[You **can** load from an external document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content#Using_external_references), as long as "that document comes from the same origin as the HTML document to which it's applied".*

Make sure the html page that has the svg effect is being passed in the URL argument along with the ID of the svg effect (for instance,

So, instead of

```
url('#filter-effect')
```

do

```
filter: url('index.html#filter-effect')
```

It wasn't obvious to me how this worked until I read @RobertLongon's comment, but it makes sense now.  You can put all your SVGs in a single document and reference them from other html files.

-

## Old Answer:

### Mozilla Developer Network says:

> > You may specify SVG in styles either within the same document, or within an external style sheet.

...but they're full of it.  Bug report?

#### use `<style>` instead of `<link>`

For reasons beyond my comprehension, if you declare the `.blur` class outside the html document, via `<link>`, your element will disappear while still occupying space.  This is why the fiddles are working in other answers but implementation is not.  JSFiddle appends your styles within the document using `<style>`.  To avoid this behavior, you should instead declare the `.blur` class WITHIN the document, aka `<style>...</style>`

Also important:

> > NOTE: Namespacing is not valid in HTML5, leave off the "svg:" in tags for HTML-format documents.

Again, `<style>`, not `<link>`.

sources:
trial and error
[mdn: Applying SVG effects to HTML content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content)

Comment: If you write #xxx that shorthand for <this file>#xxx and there's no gaussian blur element in your stylesheet. That's why it disappears because the relevent specifications (SVG and CSS) say it should to indicate an error. If you prepend your html file name to #xxx in the stylesheet it will work as you wish it to.

Comment: Interesting, but I don't understand what the `#xxx` represents.  As I understand it now, you mean the rules should be prepended with the file name, like `<example.html>#blur-element { ... }`?

Comment: In this question's case its #blur (I used xxx to mean whatever youre' using so in your case xxx is blur-element). #div-with-content{
        filter: url("example.html#blur");
    }

Comment: Okay, this makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same behavior with a filter I was trying to use. It turns out that I had also set the SVG where the filter was defined to `display: none;`. Once I removed that, the filters were available and the HTML elements they were applied to displayed properly.

Answer (score -2):

This is probably 2 years too late, but Name calling the document didn't do it for me, but placing the style directly on the element like this worked perfectly:

```
<div class="imageblur" style="filter:url(#blur) ">
```